# How to compress HTML tags mapping script in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, compression

I wrote a script that maps all the HTML tags in the page and build a tree-structure of them.
Example: 
HTML, HEAD, TITLE, BODY, DIV, H1, A, TABLE, FORM, A.

I need a compress algorithm to minimize as much as possible the tags names.
Something that will shortcut the tags names or create a unique IDs for each tag.
For example, the structure above will compress to something like:
Ht,He,Ti,B,D,h1,a, ta,fo,a
or
1,2,10,3,5,11,6,12,13,6 (Every tag has a unique ID).

How can I start? there is a published script that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering why you'd build your own tree structure of the DOM when the DOM already is a tree structure you can access from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please include your code so that we can help give a better and more direct answer. One way you could achieve this is by using the filter method for each necessary piece of code:

```
$(document).filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "HTML";
}).text('Ht');
```

of course, this works if the tree is already placed, so if you need to do it before. To add a unique id to each tag you would have to make use of the `for();` method to add a number to each id. there are plenty of tutorials on here for this. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)